# create table like new table individually numbered

Tags: javascript, mysql, html

I'm new to all of this but decided to create an online system for our company but now stuck!

What I'm trying to do is copy a mysql table but each table have a unique number when ever the script is ran i.e. autoquoteS1, autoquoteS2 etc.

I've searched a lot for this and this is the best I can find.

```
mysql_select_db("sdbdb", $con);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS autoquoteS1 LIKE autoquoteS";
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve with this solution? Instead of 20 tables, you could just create one table with an extra column that has an incrementing value to differ between lines?

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like a problem.

you should not be creating many many copies of the same table, instead, you should be entering many many rows into a single table. (assuming the same structure)

maybe you can post your table design, and we can help you with normalization.

edit:

you may be looking for something like this:

```
quote
--------
quote_id
customer_id
total
status

quote_line_item
----------------
quote_id
line_num
quantity
amount
item_id

item
--------
item_id
description
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.  I'll try and explain what I'm intending on doing.  I have a table of quotations which has 19 columns, 10 No. of these columns (section1-10), each of these will be named different on each quotation i.e. heating, ventilation etc. then each of these will link to another table which would have 16 columns and could contain 40 rows of data, so each quote would have 400 roows of data.Hope I've made this clear!?  Thanks again.  PS,

Comment: nope not clear yet... but a little better.  sounds like maybe you are looking at a paper form?  the 10 columns will be selecting from fixed sets of values?

Comment: em.. don't know!  What I want to do is every new quote we create will be stored in a table and 10 No. records on each quote will have links(still to work out this bit also) to a new table.  So for every quote (all stored in a single table), there will be 10 No. tables.  This is the only way I can think of doing it.  Thanks

Comment: I think you just don't understand. The idea is not to create separate table for each quote, but to add a column identifying the quote instead. So all the items will be in one big table and you can obtain the content of table you requested by SELECT ...  FROM qoute WHERE qoute_number = 1 (or  any other number).

Comment: the schema i presented allows what you are talking about, and also, reuse of any given item